# Setting the route in an application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am making an MVC application and I am trying to make it go to a certain page after clicking a "Create" button. I am only learning this and I'm not sure how to phrase it :P But let me explain.:

I have 3 entities, `Year`, `Week` and `Day`. They are linked together and have their own create and delete pages etc. When you make a day you say what year and week it is in. What I want to know is after I click "Create" after putting in the data for a day, how do I make it go to the Year index page rather than the Day one? When I click "Create", it shows me the list of all the days created, I rather it take me to the list of Years.

The `Create` page CSHTML code for day is inside `@using (Html.BeginForm())`, and I tried using `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Year"))`, this does take me to the Year index page, but it does not create the day at all.

Does any one know how to go about this?

`Day` "Create" page code:

```
@model Utility3.Models.Day

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h1>Add Day</h1>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @*<h4>Day</h4>*@
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Year", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("YearID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearID)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Week Number", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("WeekID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WeekID)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Day of the Week", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DayofWeek", new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Monday", Value = "Monday", Selected=true},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Tuesday", Value = "Tuesday"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Wednesday", Value = "Wednesday"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Thursday", Value = "Thursday"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Friday", Value = "Friday"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Saturday", Value = "Saturday"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Sunday", Value = "Sunday"}
                }, "Select Day")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DayofWeek)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Reading1", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reading1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reading1)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Reading2", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reading2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reading2)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

`Year ActionResult Index`

```
// GET: /Year/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Years.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Post your action method for Year/Index

Comment: I added the `ActionResult` to the question, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, just wanted to check if it had any parameters for a redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post method, redirect to the Year Index view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Utility3.Models.Day model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View();
  }
  ....... // Save your model
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Year");
}
```